# How do you stylize a font in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

I'm trying out developing for Swift, it's going pretty well. One of the issues I'm having is finding out how to stylize fonts programmatically in the language.

For example in this label I wrote the code below for, how can I make it Helvetica Neue Ultralight for example?

```
label.font = UIFont (name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 30)
```

Answer (score 72):

I am assuming this is a custom font. For any custom font this is what you do.

1. First download and add your font files to your project in Xcode 
   (The files should appear as well in “Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources”).
2. In your Info.plist file add the key “Fonts provided by application” with type “Array”.
3. For each font you want to add to your project, create an item for the array you have created with the full name of the file including its extension (e.g. HelveticaNeue-UltraLight.ttf).
   Save your “Info.plist” file.

`label.font = UIFont (name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", size: 30)`

Comment: I would also add: do not forget to include your custom fonts in the "Copy Bundle Resources" section if you haven't already or you won't be able to use them

Comment: Why assume this is a custom font?  I think the original question is looking for the same thing I am, which is font.fontWithItalics(), or font.fontWithWeight(), analogous to font.fontWithSize().  If the answer is "it must be done by font name", then that is the answer to the question.

Comment: Upvoted for providing the custom font information. Thanks!

Answer (score 57):

A great resource is [iosfonts.com](http://iosfonts.com/), which says that the name for that font is `HelveticaNeue-UltraLight`. So you'd use this code:

```
label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", size: 30)
```

If the system can't find the font, it defaults to a 'normal' font - I think it's something like 11-point Helvetica. This can be quite confusing, always check your font names.

Answer (score 19):

You can set custom font in two ways : `design time` and `run-time`.

1. First you need to `download required font` (.ttf file format). Then, double click on the file to install it.
2. This will show a pop-up. Click on '`install font`' button.

[image: Screenshot 1]

3. This will install the font and will appear in `'Fonts'` window.

[image: Screenshot 2]

4. Now, the font is installed successfully. Drag and drop the custom font in your project. While doing this make sure that '`Add to targets`' is checked.

[image: Screenshot 3]

5. You need to make sure that this file is also added into '`Copy Bundle Resources'` present in `Build Phases` of `Targets` of your project.

[image: Screenshot 4]

6. After this you need to add this font in `Info.plist` of your project. 
   Create a new key with '`Font Provided by application`' with type as *Array*.
   Add a the font as an element with type String in Array.

[image: Screenshot 5]

**`A. Design mode :`**

7. Select the label from Storyboard file. Goto `Font` attribute present in `Attribute inspector` of `Utilities`.

[image: Screenshot 6]

8. Click on Font and select 'Custom font'

[image: Screenshot 7]

9. From Family section select the custom font you have installed.

[image: Screenshot 8]

10. Now you can see that font of label is set to custom font.

[image: Screenshot 9]

**`B. Run-time mode :`**

```
 self.lblWelcome.font = UIFont(name: "BananaYeti-Extrabold Trial", size: 16)
```

It seems that run-time mode doesn't work for dynamically formed string like

```
self.lblWelcome.text = "Welcome, " + fullname + "!"
```

Note that in above case **only design-time approach worked correctly for me.**

Answer (score 15):

Add Custom Font in Swift

1. Drag and drop your font in your project.
2. Double check that it is added in Copy Bundle Resource. (Build Phase -> Copy Bundle Resource).
3. In your plist file add "Font Provided by application" and add your fonts with full name.
4. Now use your font like: `myLabel.font = UIFont (name: "GILLSANSCE-ROMAN", size: 20)`

Comment: Thanks, m8. I'm still getting a hold on the Obj-C to Swift transition

Comment: full file name that is.

Answer (score 2):

**Xamarin**

```
Label.Font = UIFont.FromName("Copperplate", 10.0f);
```

**Swift**

```
text.font = UIFont.init(name: "Poppins-Regular", size: 14)
```

*To get the list of font family*  [Github/IOS-UIFont-Names](https://github.com/lionhylra/iOS-UIFont-Names)

Comment: GIT link is great! Thanks!