# SF UI Display doesn't work on Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

I am using the SF UI Display for iOS on Xcode and I chose the Ultralight option, and this is what shows up on the storyboard (the correct version)[image]

This is what shows on the simulator when I run it, it looks much bolder and doesn't seem right...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since San Francisco is the System Font, no need to choose custom and use San Francisco, just use system.

Comment: I'm using system on the latest Xcode and it's not showing the San Francisco font.
If I set it manually in code, it does show the .SFUIDisplay Font, but on the simulator it looks the same as Helvetica.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a button, try this

```
[button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:size weight: UIFontWeightUltraLight]];
```

If it's a label, try this:

```
[label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:size weight: UIFontWeightUltraLight]];
```

In each of those cases, replace "size" with your desired font size.

EDIT: For Swift (labels), refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708401/how-do-you-stylize-a-font-in-swift) StackOverflow post

EDIT 2: For Swift (buttons), refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002017/how-to-change-font-of-uibutton-with-swift) StackOverflow post